# Why does the word unthinkable exist?

Tags: word-usage

If unthinkable means unlikely to happen, why is it called unthinkable?

Comment: *"If unthinkable means unlikely"*  It doesn't mean unlikely. What dictionary are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/unthinkable#etymonline_v_25312) of the word *unthinkable*

> early 15c., "too large to be conceived, unimaginable," from un- (1)
> "not" + think (v.) + -able. Meaning "incapable of being framed by
> thought" is recorded from mid-15c.

As to "why it exists", that's slightly harder to answer. I guess one could ask the same of every word in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete definition of the word:
[American Heritage Dictionary "unthinkable"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unthinkable)

> 1. Impossible to imagine; inconceivable: *"The inert gases have been coaxed into combination, and I have seen a fluoride of xenon, unthinkable in the 1940s" (Oliver Sacks).*
> 2. Not worth considering because of being socially unacceptable, too difficult, or too risky: *Raising taxes was politically unthinkable.*
> 3. Abhorrent; monstrous: *unthinkable brutality.*

As you can see, the word "unthinkable" means a lot more than "impossible".

Here's a definition of the suffix:
[American Heritage Dictionary "-able or -ible"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=-able)

> suffix.
>
> 1. Susceptible, capable, or worthy of a specified action: debatable.
> 2. Inclined or given to a specified state or action: changeable.